# NPM update error - Fails to execute GIT

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, aurelia

When I try to create a project I get the error below.
It seems to be network related because it occurs only in company network.
Any idea how to troubleshoot that?

> D:\Projects\aurelia>au new test3
>
> . . .
>
> Installing project dependencies. npm ERR! git clone
>
> --template=C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-r emotes_templates --mirror git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git
>
> C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0ecf98f08
>
> : npm ERR! git clone
>
> --template=C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git
>
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-40-4b46db44: npm ERR! git clone
>
> --template=C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git
>
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801:

**UPDATE**

This what I get when I run `npm install`

[image]

If I copy paste the git command that fails I get this:

> error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.
>   Details:error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while
>   accessing https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git/info/refs  fatal: HTTP
>   request failed

**UPDATE**

I added the missing certificate to git, and now I can run the git command by itself successfully. If I run `npm install` I still get an error.
I also followed the advice of @Andrew and modified the git config file.

Comment: Added an answer, let me know if that actually works for you. If not, hit me up on Gitter (astoker) and I can try and get you up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring your git to use https instead of git. That seems to work more frequently inside work networks.
Type this command into your console:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Then you can try to create the project again, or just run `npm install` if it's already been created and it just failed on the dependency retrieval step.

Additionally, if [that doesn't work](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5257), you might need to further specify when npm is using git with ssh. In this case, run this command as well:

`git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that but I still get the same error. Running npm inside the project gives lots of errors.

Comment: Specifically the same errors? Are you able to talk to your IT guy and see if they're blocking any specific ports to Git?  
Also, are you able to run npm install for any individual package (say jQuery)?

Comment: I posted a print screen with the errors I get when I run npm install and when I run git. My main concern is what to ask from the IT guy.

Comment: Also I should mention that when I posted this question the git command worked fine, only when executed from npm there was an issue which makes me think that something changed in the meantime.

Comment: What happens when you try to install an individual package, not the whole shebang?

Comment: follow the instruction, git uses the configuration without problem, but when git is called by NPM, the error appear again

Comment: @XtianGIS, updated the answer. You might need to specify the ssh setup as well

Comment: @user905374, Have you "signed into" Git-Hub with your command line? Git-Hub only allows so many anonymous requests at a time, and it's possible that you've run against that wall.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll check and let  you know,  I'll also reinstall node which is from last year.

Comment: @user905374, either use Node v4.5(LTS), or the latest, v6.6.0.

Comment: Kicks and giggles, install v6.6.0. Did you sign into Github from the command line too?