# Is possible to change in Aurelia the way that Aurelia-CLI connects to Github?

Tags: aurelia

- **Library Version:**
  0.19

**Please tell us about your environment:**
* **Operating System:**
Windows 7
* **Node Version:**
6.3.1

- **NPM Version:**
  3.10.5
- **Browser:**
  all
- **Language:**
  all

**Current behavior:**
Trying to perform the command **au new --here** but at the end of the wizard due to security issues I got:

```
Installing project dependencies.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\R
oaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by pee
r
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: and the repository exists.
```

it would be nice to have an option to use http connection to github.com not only the SSH connection

some companies have its development teams behind firewalls and security policies, and are not able to proceed to use this tool

Comment: This is a npm issue, I'm pretty sure. Check out this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386416/aurelia-cli-au-new-error/39415623)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before, and potentially answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39415623/2333442

### For the sake of others finding this question, try these steps.

Try configuring your git to use https instead of git. That seems to work more frequently inside work networks.
Type this command into your console:

`git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`
Then you can try to create the project again, or just run npm install if it's already been created and it just failed on the dependency retrieval step.

Additionally, if that doesn't work, you might need to further specify when npm is using git with ssh. In this case, run this command as well:
`git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`

Comment: been there, done that. 
Does not work because npm, somehow overrides the configuration of GIT

Comment: What was the output of that?